# How to Display Multiple MongoDB Collections using express and Handlebars

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express-handlebars

I have a MongoDB with 2 collections. I am only able to display 1 
collection ("contents")  using the following function in my index.js. I'm not able to display the second collection "internals".

```
res.render('Westlands', {title: 'Westlands Branch', contents: content, 
internals: Internal});
```

I have more than 2 collections I'd like to display on a menu item on the web page. I get the First collection (contents) to display using :-

```
res.render('Westlands', {title: 'Westlands Branch', contents: content, 
internals: Internal});
```

But internals shows blank on the page.I created 
the project using "express [folder-name] --hbs
Mongo server ver. 4.0.10

```
This is my index.js 
//index.js
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
var Content = require('../models/content');
var Internal = require('../models/internal');

/* GET home page. */
router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
  res.render('index', { title: 'PACIS Internal Contacts' });
   });
 /* GET Userlist page. */
router.get('/westlands', function(req, res, next) {  
Content.find(function(err, content){
var Internal = require('../models/internal');
var internals = Internal.find();
res.render('westlands', {title: 'Westlands Branch', contents: content, 
internals: Internal});    
   });     
});
//This works great. I can view the data. The collection name is contents
    //.hbs file
    {{# each contents }}
    <hr><p>{{ this.fname }} {{ lname }}, {{ this.title }}, Ext: {{ 
     this.extension }} </p>                    
    {{/each}}

//This does not work. I get a blank. Collection Name is internals
  </li>
  <li id="b"><a href="#b">Internal Audit</a>
  {{# each internals}}                    
     <hr><p>{{ this.fname }} {{ lname }}, {{ this.title }}, {{ 
     this.extension }} </p> 
  {{/each}}         


 //Models are similar

 var mongoose = require('mongoose');
  var schema = new Schema({
    fname: {type: String, required: true},
    lname: {type: String, required: true},
    title: {type: String, required: true},
    email: {type: String, required: true},
    department: {type: String, required: true},
    branch: {type: String, required: true},
    extension: {type: Number, required: true},
    dline: {type: Number, required: true}

 });

//model name is Internal
module.exports = mongoose.model('Internal', schema); 


var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;

var schema = new Schema({
    fname: {type: String, required: true},
    lname: {type: String, required: true},
    title: {type: String, required: true},
    email: {type: String, required: true},
    department: {type: String, required: true},
    branch: {type: String, required: true},
    extension: {type: Number, required: true},
    dline: {type: Number, required: true}

  });

    //model name is Content

   module.exports = mongoose.model('Content', schema);
```

I have two menu items on my web App each labeled. By clicking I should 
be able to display the collections.